# php variables in .php file of a smarty based web app(care2x)

Tags: php, templates, variables, smarty

I'm modifying a web app (care2x) which is uses smarty for templating.
as you all know smarty uses two files .php for logic code and .tpl for template.

In .php file some php variables are used to assign to smarty variables
for example

```
$this->smarty->assign('template-variable',$php-variable);
```

I can't figure out where $php-variable gets its value from?
is it same as passing values from controller to view in ci?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean that `$php-variable` is variable from PHP because in variable names you cannot use `-` sign.

Those variables of course come simple from PHP, so what you should do is to search simply in PHP files this variable. They can be defined in the same file or in other files depending on system architecture.

The easiest way of course is when variable is defined just before assigning its value to Smarty as following

```
$phpVar = 2;
$this->smarty->assign('template-variable',$phpVar);
```

but in case it's not, you should probably use your editor or for example Total Commander to find this variable.

Without any more details and full code it's hard to say where it can be defined.